# c function returning nan instead of double

Tags: c, methods, recursion, nan, bisection

We're taking up numerical methods in my programming class and the first algorithm introduced to us was the bisection method for root finding. Here's my attempt at implementing it using recursion:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define tolerance 0.00001

double my_function(double z){
    double answer = 5*pow(z,2) + 5*z - 2;

    return answer;
} 

double bisection(double (*fxn)(double),double a, double b){

    double m = ((a+b)/2);

    if (fabs(b-a) < tolerance){
        double root = a;
        printf("value of a is %lf\n",root);
        return a;
    }



    else if (fxn(m) > 0){
        b = m;
    }

    else if (fxn(m) < 0){
        a = m;  
    } 

    bisection(my_function, a, b);
}

int main(){

    double g = 0.01;
    double z = 1;

    double x = bisection(my_function,g,z);
    printf("root is %lf\n",x);  

return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
value of a is 0.306225
root is nan
```

The root is correct (slightly off, but within the tolerance level) but somewhere in between returning the value and printing it, it somehow turns into NaN. I'm stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `bisection(my_function, a, b);` here you should probably use `bisection(fxn, a, b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning from the recursive call.  Change the last statement in `bisection` to

```
return bisection(my_function, a, b);
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you please explain why that matters? Shouldn't my one return statement be enough?

Comment: No, if you do not include the return on the last statement, nothing is returned and hence, the value assigned to `x` in `main` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess:

in the section

```
if (fabs(b-a) < tolerance){
    double root = a;
    printf("value of a is %lf\n",root);
    return a;
}
```

You return a instead of root. Try returning root and see if that helps.